# Setting up SSL on Domain.com

Tags: ssl, heroku

I currently have a domain from domain.com. I have a heroku domain name and a dns target. I have also enabled the free ssl on domain.com.

```
Example: 
Heroku: domain: www.test.com DNS Target: crazytarget.herokudns.com
Domain.com: Record: CNAME, Name: WWW, Content: crazytarget.herokudns.com
```

Note: This works for non-https.

I uploded a .htaccess file onto heroku so now the heroku domain is served at https://path.herokuapp.com.

This domain name cname does NOT pick up the https version of the site.

My question is: How do I get my domain to use https? I dont see how to do this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had to setup SSL on the Heroku end. :(